# How to update last login using authcomp in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.7

I am currently using Auth component to login. I want to update last_login field in  my users table whenever a user login to my site.

My login function in Users controller i have--

```
public function login() {
 $this->layout = 'main';
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
 if($this->Auth->login()) {
   $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'dashboard'));  // after login , redirect on dahsboard
  }
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
  }
   $this->redirect(Router::url('/', true));  // there is no login.ctp file so it always redirect on home
}
```

In app controller i have

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Auth',
    'Session',
);

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array( 
       'controller' => 'pages',
      'action' => 'display','home'
     );
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "update last_login field" ? Is it a field for last login user_id or date-time ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to execute one simple update query after successful login by adding this

```
$user = $this->Session->read("Auth.User");
$this->User->id = $user['id'];
$this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

There are several other method to update last_login field:
1.

```
$data['User']['last_login']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->User->save($data);
```

2.

```
$this->User->updateAll(array('User.last_login'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),array('User.id'=>$user['id']));
```

After this your code will look like this,

```
public function login() {
 $this->layout = 'main';
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
 if($this->Auth->login()) {
       $user = $this->Session->read("Auth.User");
       $this->User->id = $user['id'];
       $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

   $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'dashboard'));  // after login , redirect on dahsboard
  }
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
  }
   $this->redirect(Router::url('/', true));  
// there is no login.ctp file so it always redirect on home
}
```